# Zurb foundation alerts

Tags: alert, zurb-foundation

I am integrating zurb foundation into an existing ASPX site. I wanted to add some information into an alert box so I used the code provided in the documentation which is:

```
<div class="alert-box secondary">
  This is a secondary alert (div.alert-box.secondary).
  <a href="" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

I have not been successful with this actually closing the message. Is there something else I'm supposed to add to this code in order for it to work? Like should the link in the close element link back to the page? I have it in there right now just as seen above and it doesn't work. So far all of my other elements from Zurb have worked fine, like navigation, buttons, tabs, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you importing correctly the [Javascript libraries](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascripts.php) needed for the alert box to work?

The file `jquery.foundation.alerts.js` should be called when the page loads (you can check this in the Network tab in the browser inspector) or included in the `app.js` file that is later compressed/minified file.

Also you need to initialize it with

```
$(document).foundationAlerts();
```

Comment: Ah, I see that my jquery files weren't being loaded with the page and I fixed that. Also do I initialize it within my code? What would be a complete example? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This doesn't work for Foundation 5. Probably the correct solution in this case is executing: `$(document).foundation('alert');`
But I'm not sure.

Comment: For Foundation 5, I had to include $(document).foundation('alert','events'); in my application.js in order for the alerts to close.

Comment: @earthsmurf even that didn't work for me, so I ended up rolling my own close action: `$('.alert-box > a.close').click(function() { $(this).closest('[data-alert]').fadeOut(); });`

Answer (score 8):

'Don't forget to add 'data-alert' to your block element. That had me pulling my hair out for a bit. I had one alert working and the other not.. it was just that I had forgotten the 'data-alert'.

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box">
    Content
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that data_alert is not the same as data-alert.  Should be obvious I know, but....well I'm mentioning it because such a comment could have saved me a lot of time last week.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when I was injecting HTML into my page via AJAX. My solution was a hack.

I add in the following element under the body.

```
<span data-alert />
```

I think the HTML5 *data-alert* is required for the element to load.

Once this was done, the dismiss worked fine.

Comment: any ideas why this worked? it worked for me to for Foundation 5.2.2.